# Copying content from a hidden or clipped window in XP?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface

I need to copy the content of a window (BitBlt) which is hidden, to another window. The problem is that once I hide the source window, the device context I got isn't painted anymore.

Answer (score 10):

What you need is the [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535695.aspx) function that's available in Win32 API since Windows XP. If you need it to work with older versions of Windows, you can try [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534856(VS.85).aspx), although I've never been able to make it work.

There's a nice article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997649.aspx) that shows how to use PrintWindow, and here's the relevant code snippet from that article:

```
// Takes a snapshot of the window hwnd, stored in the memory device context hdcMem
HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
if (hdc)
{
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if (hdcMem)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, RECTWIDTH(rc), RECTHEIGHT(rc));
        if (hbitmap)
        {
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbitmap);

            PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcMem, 0);

            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        }
        DeleteObject(hdcMem);
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

I should have some Python code that uses wxPython to achieve the same thing. Drop me a note if you want it.

Comment: I've always wondered if PrintWindow() uses its own logic, or if it just posts a WM_PRINT to the given window. MSDN seems to be vague on that point. Time for a test program to check that ...

Comment: It uses its own logic, not WM_PRINT.

Comment: @DavidK: The current version of the documentation clearly says that `WM_PRINT` or `WM_PRINTCLIENT` is sent.

Comment: PrintWindow has the advantage that it also prints the window if it is covered by another window or even outside the monitor. But the price you pay is that many non-Microsoft applications do not handle WM_PRINTCLIENT and you end up with a blank bitmap. Another problem that remains is that PrintWindow only copies the part to the bitmap that is visible on the screen. If your window has a scrollbar and shows it's content only partially, this code is not usefull.

Comment: How to get the part of the window that is hidden at the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the source bitmap to a memory bitmap before closing/hiding the window.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sending a `WM_PRINT` message to the window. For many windows (including all standard windows and common controls) this will cause it to paint into the supplied DC.

Also, if you pass an HDC as the wparam of a WM_PAINT message, many windows (such as the common controls) will paint into that DC rather than onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can trigger a redraw operation on the window with InvalidateRect?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you're going to have real problems getting this to work reliably. You don't say exactly what you're doing, but I assume that, given the window handle, you're grabbing the device context associated with the window by calling GetWindowDC(), and then using the resulting device context.

This will work okay on XP when the window is visible. However, on Vista, if desktop compositing is enabled, it won't even work properly then: you'll get 0 back from GetWindowDC(). Fundamentally, grabbing window device contexts isn't going to work reliably.

If the window you're trying to copy from is part of your own application, I'd suggest modifying your code to support the WM___PRINT message: this acts like WM_PAINT, but allows you to supply a device context to draw into.

If the window isn't from your application, you're basically out of luck: if the window is hidden, the image of what it would show if it were visible doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The PrintWindow function doesn't seem to work on a hidden window, only on visible ones.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching things from a different perspective, are you sure that's really what you want to be doing?  You don't, for example, want to be using CreateCompatibleDC and CreateCompatibleBitmap to create your invisible drawing surface, drawing on that and then using BitBlt?

Some more information about the background to what you're up to might enable someone to come up with either a solution or some lateral thinking...

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909.aspx (getPixel) might help...

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in Windows 7, should work fine from XP up.

It brings the window to the foreground without giving it focus, before capturing it.  It's not perfection, but it's the best you're going to do if you can't get PrintWindow() to work.

It's a static method, so you just can simply call it like so:

```
Orwellophile.TakeScreenShotOfWindow("window.jpg", Form.Handle);
```

No mess, no fuss.  It's from a larger class, so hopefully nothing is missing.  The originals are:

http://sfinktah.trac.cvsdude.com/vhddirector/browser/main/VHD%20Director/UnhandledExceptionManager.cs
and http://sfinktah.trac.cvsdude.com/vhddirector/browser/main/CSharp.cc/Win32Messaging.cs although they're nowhere as neat as the example I've pasted below.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Orwellophile {
    public static void TakeScreenshotOfWindow(String strFilename, IntPtr hTargetWindow)
    {
        Rectangle objRectangle;
        RECT r;
        IntPtr hForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

        GetWindowRect(hTargetWindow, out r);
        objRectangle = r.ToRectangle();

        if (hTargetWindow != hForegroundWindow)
        {
            ShowWindow(hTargetWindow, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
            SetWindowPos(hTargetWindow.ToInt32(), HWND_TOPMOST, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height, SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        TakeScreenshotPrivate(strFilename, objRectangle);
    }

    private static void TakeScreenshotPrivate(string strFilename, Rectangle objRectangle)
    {
        Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(objRectangle.Width, objRectangle.Height);
        Graphics objGraphics = default(Graphics);
        IntPtr hdcDest = default(IntPtr);
        int hdcSrc = 0;

        objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);


        hdcSrc = GetDC(0);                  // Get a device context to the windows desktop and our destination  bitmaps
        hdcDest = objGraphics.GetHdc();     // Copy what is on the desktop to the bitmap
        BitBlt(hdcDest.ToInt32(), 0, 0, objRectangle.Width, objRectangle.Height, hdcSrc, objRectangle.X, objRectangle.Y, SRCCOPY);
        objGraphics.ReleaseHdc(hdcDest);    // Release DC
        ReleaseDC(0, hdcSrc);

        objBitmap.Save(strFilename);
    }


    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc, int nWidth, int nHeight);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hgdiobj);
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags); // To capture only the client area of window, use PW_CLIENTONLY = 0x1 as nFlags
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(
         int hWnd,           // window handle
         int hWndInsertAfter,    // placement-order handle
         int X,          // horizontal position
         int Y,          // vertical position
         int cx,         // width
         int cy,         // height
         uint uFlags);       // window positioning flags
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static public extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
    private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    private const int SRCCOPY = 0xcc0020;
}
```

Note that you can implement your own light-weight RECT class/struct, but this is the one I use.  I've attached it separately due to it's size

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(System.Drawing.Rectangle Rectangle)
        : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
        _Left = Left;
        _Top = Top;
        _Right = Right;
        _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right
    {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom
    {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value - _Top; }
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location
    {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set
        {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }
    public Size Size
    {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set
        {
            _Right = value.Height + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle ToRectangle()
    {
        return new Rectangle(this.Left, this.Top, this.Width, this.Height);
    }
    static public Rectangle ToRectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.ToRectangle();
    }
    static public RECT FromRectangle(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }

    static public implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.ToRectangle();
    }
    static public implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle);
    }
    static public bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    static public bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT)
        {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        }
        else if (Object is Rectangle)
        {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Left.GetHashCode() ^ Right.GetHashCode() ^ Top.GetHashCode() ^ Bottom.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the question. What you do is easy! But if the window is bigger than the monitor or clipped your code will capture it only partially! The question was how to capture a window that is behind another window or hidden or clipped.

Comment: This code is extremely awkward. You can do the same with 3 lines of code without any DllImport by using Graphics.CopyFromScreen()

Answer (score 0):

For a window that is hidden behind another window you can set it to be transparent (with a high alpha so that it doesn't look transparent).  It should then be possible to capture the whole window with BitBlt.