# Take a screen capture of an invisible window

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible (on Windows 7) to take a screen capture of an invisible window (i.e. one without the WM_VISIBLE flag?) Preferably the method would be high-performance, so I could take hundreds of these screenshot / second.

Comment: What does an invisible window look like?

Comment: @Bo Normal applications are started, and then I remove the WM_VISIBLE flag from their windows so that they do not render to the screen anymore. I would still like to render them somewhere else, though.

Comment: The goal is to start an application, but instead of it rendering to the screen, I hide it and can render it myself by taking screen captures.

Comment: @IsaacWaller : If a window is not intended to be visible, who's to say it even bothers painting anything?

Comment: @ildjarn: I want to force the window to render, so I can take a screenshot of it

Comment: @IsaacWaller : I ask again, if an application was written in a way that it was intended to be invisible, who says the application's author even wrote any painting/rendering code?

Comment: @ildjarn: The application is a normal application (like Photoshop, Chrome, etc.) The only difference is that after it launches, I hide the window, so that it does not render to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will find some useful information here:
[Copying content from a hidden or clipped window in XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242570/copying-content-from-a-hidden-or-clipped-window-in-xp)

Comment: PrintWindow does not always work on Windows 7. I believe it is due to the new window rendering system in Vista and up.

Answer (score 0):

Well-written Windows programs check that a window is visible before they paint themselves.

You are telling these windows not to render themselves, and then expecting them to render themselves.  That is simply not going to work.

Comment: Is there any way I can trick the window into thinking it is rendered?

Comment: Maybe you can just set the window visible but move it off-screen, then it will still render? (windows 7 anyway)

Comment: @roger off screen windows don't render

Comment: Have you tested that in windows 7?  Seems to work for me here...unless your app is smart enough to recognize it's off the window and not draw, then you're done again.

Comment: @roger probably works there with aero thumb preview but not likely on xp

Comment: @David that appears to be it exactly.