# Using PrintWindow with gcc and codeblocks

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I want to use a code snippet from this post:  [Copying content from a hidden or clipped window in XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242570/copying-content-from-a-hidden-or-clipped-window-in-xp) has an example using this.  .  But in Code::Blocks I have error that "`PrintWindow` isn't declared in this scope". What should I do? Does this code work only in Visual C++ (with MFC etc.) ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#include <windows.h>` if that does not work it probably is only going to work in VC++ because the library is distributed using a .lib and a .dll and C::B can not read .lib files which you need to use to link the library this function is located in.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx