# Getting Pixel Values "Under" Current Window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, screenshot

I'm trying to make, essentially, a screen capture program, that captures the pixel values under the current window. (I'm working in C#, in Visual Studio 2015.) However, for various reasons, the window itself needs to be opaque (for filters and such). How can I best achieve this?

Comment: I belive it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to find the window below yours and get a screenshot of it even if it is hidden with the method: [PrintWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869.aspx) (see [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/PrintWindow.html) as well)

See [Copying content from a hidden or clipped window in XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242837/704281)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to do in Winforms.  Just set the form's Opacity value to 99%.  Now Graphics.CopyFromScreen() will not see your window anymore.

Except when the window underneath yours is also a layered window, then it also won't be visible to CopyFromScreen() for the same reason.  Then you have to set Opacity to 0, copy and set it back to 0.99.  Very quick, probably good enough for what you want to do.